# How to create a simple webservice function in moodle?

Tags: moodle

i wants to create a simple function that prints a message hello world in moodle.
How can i create a simple webservice function in moodle.

Comment: In moodle, you can create the functionality by tweaking module, plugin, theme. So it's depends upon what you want to create.

Comment: Plz, Send a sample function code over here..